# NSAttributedString error. It's appending the description of the attributes dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I'm creating an attributed string and conditionally applying a strikethrough. Here's the code:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if (needsStrikeThrough) {
        [attributes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] forKey:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName];
    } else {
        [attributes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleNone] forKey:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName];
    }
    NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:participant.firstName attributes:attributes];
    NSLog(@"attString= %@", attString);
    NSLog(@"[attributes description]= %@", [attributes description]);
```

The output in the console is this:

```
attributedParticipantName= Belinda{
    NSStrikethrough = 0;
 }
[attributes description]= {
    NSStrikethrough = 0;
}
```

So the description of the dictionary is being appended to the attributed string. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how the `description` method of `NSAttributedString` is implemented. It's designed to help you with debugging, so that you can inspect the attributes of a string in the (plain text) console. The actual string is just the part before the curly braces ("Belinda"). To print just the string, without any attributes, you could log `attString.string`.